# Tortoise SVN Checkout - Malformed XML No Element found

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have created a repository on a debian linux server:

```
svnadmin create --fs-type fsfs myrepo
```

This has created a folder here:

```
/var/svn/myrepo
```

If I create a folder on my Windows computer and right-click and select SVN checkout with the following URL:

```
http://192.168.2.180/var/svn/myrepo
```

I get the following error:

```
Unable to connect to a repository at URL http://192.168.2.180/var/svn/myrepo
The XML response contains invalid XML
Malformed XML: no element found
```

The IP address is correct for the server.

If I run `svnadmin info myrepo` I get:

```
Path: myrepo
UUID: 11f2b186-a170-4dea-8466-512defeeea98
Repository Format: 5
Compatible With Version: 1.9.0
Repository Capability: mergeinfo
Filesystem Type: fsfs
Filesystem Format: 7
FSFS Sharded: yes
FSFS Shard Size: 1000
FSFS Shards Packed: 0/0
FSFS Logical Addressing: yes
Configuration File: myrepo/db/fsfs.conf
```

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: For http(s) access you need a web server with correspondent SVN module installed (e.g. Apache with `mod_dav_svn`). Just exporting the directory as web site isn't enough.

Answer (score 0):

As the comment by Robert suggests for http access you need to have apache running with mod_dav_svn. 
For a tutorial on how to do it you can refer to the following link:

https://www.krizna.com/ubuntu/setup-svn-server-on-ubuntu-14-04/

This link will help you how to setup apache, subversion and write a apache configuration for the same.